# Electron/Node.js - How to spawn a python script from another directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, electron

I currently have the following file structure for my electron project:

```
<PROJECT>
      <css>
      <js>
      <data>
      <scripts>
            script.py
      index.html
      main.js
      package.json
```

In my `main.js` I have

```
var ipc = require('electron').ipcMain;

ipc.on('asynchronous-message', function (event, arg) {
    var py = require('child_process').spawn('python', ['./scripts/script.py']);
    py.on('close', function() {
        event.sender.send('asynchronous-reply', '');
    });
});
```

But the python script (which actually generates an output file) doesn't seem to run at all. If I take the script out of the `scripts` folder and place it in the top level folder right next to the `main.js` file and change the `spawn` agruments array to `['./script.py']`, it runs perfectly fine. I'm just not entirely sure what part of the code above is causing the script to fail to execute.

Answer (score 1):

Always use absolute paths, to create one relative to the current source file prefix it with `__dirname`, for example:

```
const path = require('path');
const scriptFilename = path.join(__dirname, 'scripts', 'script.py');
```